# Using Ctrl+/ in WebStorm vuejs3 Style tag adds // causes an error

Tags: vuejs3, webstorm

[image]

Normally it should add the `/**/` comment

How to fix this?

WebStorm 2023.3.4, Windows 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When they don't have a `lang` attribute, `<style />` tags in Vue SFCs are interpreted as PostCSS.

Go to `Settings | Editor | Code Style | Style Sheets | CSS | PostCSS` and check that `/* comment */` is selected.

---

Related YouTrack issues:

- [PostCSS: comments style option is not taken into accont inside vue style tag](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-59441)
- [Wrong comment style in Vue 3  tags](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-65982)